# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function attributes() on null

Tags: php

Есть xml:

```
<metadata xmlns="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#" xmlns:ns2="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/ext#-2.0" created="2018-08-01T18:05:33.207Z">
    <recording-list count="1712634" offset="0">
    ...
```

Пытаюсь получить доступ к значению атрибута `count`:

```
$xml_workflow = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$releases_found = intval($xml_workflow->metadata->{'recording-list'}->attributes()['count']);
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function attributes() on null

Что не так в моём коде? Атрибуты же есть у xml-элемента.

Answer (score 2):

В вашей строке имеется лишний элемент `metadata`:

```
intval($xml_workflow->metadata->{'recording-list'}->attributes()['count']);
```

Поэтому стоит записать так:

```
$releases_found = (int) $xml_workflow->{'recording-list'}->attributes()['count'];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Что не так в моём коде?

Походу да

```
// Для примера взята строка XML следующего содержания
$string = <<<XML
<metadata xmlns="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#" xmlns:ns2="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/ext#-2.0" created="2018-08-01T18:05:33.207Z">
    <recording-list count="1712634" offset="0">
    </recording-list>
    </metadata>
XML;
// Загружается из строки
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
// Не нужно использовать metadata, просто обратитесь к $xml->{'recording-list'}
foreach($xml->{'recording-list'}->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

Результат:

```
count="1712634"
offset="0"
```